Can i use HMS core push kit for handling push notification in ios react native?
while doing HmsPushInstanceId.getToken('') to get device token for push notification service, its giving undefined. HmsPushInstanceId itself is showing as null.

I am trying to implement push notification using HMS core push kit in
my react native app.
Its working fine for android but not working in case of iOS.
I am getting HmsPushInstanceId as null.
I followed the steps for ios as provided in documentation.HMS
iOS

Trying to figure out the issue from past 3 days.
Can anybody help?
Note: I am using HMS Core for china.
This is how i am trying to retrieve the device token
import {
    HmsPushEvent,
    HmsPushInstanceId,
    HmsPushMessaging,
} from '@hmscore/react-native-hms-push';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { isDeviceInChina } from '../../globalization/utils/getCountry';

function useHuwaeiPushService({ setUserAndToken = () => {} }) {

    const getHuwaeiPushToken = async () => {
        if (!isDeviceInChina()) {
            return;
        }

        HmsPushInstanceId?.getToken('')
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('getToken::', result);
                setUserAndToken((pv) => {
                    return {
                        ...pv,
                        messagingToken: result?.result,
                    };
                });
                activateHuwaeiPush();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`[getToken] Error/Exception: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
            });
    };

    return {
        getHuwaeiPushToken,
    };
}

export default useHuwaeiPushService;


